# Not all query datasources available on ListPage

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012

In the MSDN tutorial on [adding data sources to a list page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc596921.aspx), it says

> Expand the Data Sources node for the list page. The node includes the
>   query that you added and the data sources associated with that query.

However I noticed not all the datasources of the query for the CustTable list page are available.

Can anyone tell me the criteria for the datasources being available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataSources with `JoinMode` `ExistJoin` or `NotExistJoin` are not available.

And make sure that query version on the `Data Sources` of the list page is same as the query version in the AOT. If not click into Query property and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image: DataSource Query Version]

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa880078.aspx

Comment: I have added a datasource with join type InnerJoin